# php mailer cannot send email to anyone except myself

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using php mailer class to send email to my customers. But it failed with error:

```
Language string failed to load: recipients_failed example@gmail.com
```

If I change the values of $email_to and $email_from to the same email address, then the email is sent successful

This is my code for sending the email

```
$email_to = "example@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "bla bla";
$email_from = 'info@domain.com.vn';
$email_message = "hello there";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com.vn"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->AddAddress($email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);     
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
$mail->WordWrap = 100; 
$mail->Body = $htmlBody;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AltBody = $email_message;
if(!$mail->Send()){
   echo $mail->ErrorInfo; 
}
```

So it will always report error unless I change $email_to to info@domain.com.vn

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe your local smtp need login informations.

Comment: you want to use your code in your local system or live

Comment: sory, how can I know whether I need login infomartion? thanks

Comment: then use $mail->IsHTML(false); and no hose name require $mail->Host = "mail.domain.com.vn"; // SMTP server comment hose line

Comment: This just means you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and this problem will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** Please change the SMTP server setting to your own server.

```
$your_email = "info@example.com";
$your_smtp = "mail.example.com";
$your_smtp_user = "info@example.com";
$your_smtp_pass = "example_password";
$your_website = "http://example.com";

//get contact form details
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$response="Name: $name\nContents:\n$comments\n";

$mail = new PHPmailer();
$mail = $mail->SetLanguage("en", "phpmailer/language");
$mail->From = $your_email;
$mail->FromName = $your_website;
$mail->Host = $your_smtp;
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->Password = $your_smtp_pass;
$mail->Username = $your_smtp_user;
$mail->Subject = "$your_website feedback";
$mail->SMTPAuth  =  "true";
$mail->Body = $response;
$mail->AddAddress($your_email,"$your_website admin");
$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);

echo "<p>Thanks for your feedback, <em>$name</em>! We will contact you soon!</p>";
if (!$mail->Send()) {
echo "<p>There was an error in sending mail, please try again at a later time</p>";
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the language and path to your language files like this:

```
$mail->SetLanguage ("de", "./phpmailer/");
```

If this doesn't fix. Make sure the language files really exist in that folder (use a relative path if possible) AND under Linux: the files should have the same owner as your php script and correct (read file rights).